# drm.ko missing for CUDA 6.5 / Ubuntu 14.04 / AWS EC2 GPU instance g2.2xlarge

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cuda, nvidia, ubuntu-14.04

To install CUDA 6.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on AWS EC2 g2.2xlarge instance, whether I install via the .deb file or .run file

```
.sudo ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --kernel-source-path=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic
```

I always get the same error about a missing **drm.ko**. The code compilation seems successful. Below was the log. (I rebooted before installing)

> Kernel module compilation complete.
>
> Unable to determine if Secure Boot is enabled: No such file or directory
>
> Kernel module load error: No such file or directory
>
> Kernel messages:
>
> [    3.595939] type=1400 audit(1408809902.911:5): apparmor="STATUS"
>
> operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>
> name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=492
>
> comm="apparmor_parser"
>
> [    3.595942] type=1400 audit(1408809902.911:6): apparmor="STATUS"
>
> operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>
> name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=492
>
> comm="apparmor_parser"
>
> [    3.596140] type=1400 audit(1408809902.915:7): apparmor="STATUS"
>
> operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>
> operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>
> name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=492
>
> comm="apparmor_parser"
>
> [    4.696067] init: failsafe main process (833) killed by TERM signal
>
> [    4.793261] type=1400 audit(1408809904.107:8): apparmor="STATUS"
>
> operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient"
>
> pid=952 comm="apparmor_parser"
>
> [    4.793267] type=1400 audit(1408809904.107:9): apparmor="STATUS"
>
> operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>
> name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=952
>
> comm="apparmor_parser"
>
> [    5.036249] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended,
> respawning
>
> [    6.589233] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (1203)
> terminated
>
> with status 1
>
> [  136.367014] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
>
> [  136.367019] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
>
> [  136.370281] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or
>
> required key missing - tainting kernel
>
> [  136.370383] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_open (err 0)
>
> [  136.370393] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_poll (err 0)
>
> [  136.370404] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_init (err 0)
>
> [  136.370449] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd (err
> 0)
>
> [  136.370462] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_private_object_init (err
> 0)
>
> [  136.370474] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_mmap (err 0)
>
> [  136.370478] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_ioctl (err 0)
>
> [  136.370486] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_object_free (err 0)
>
> [  136.370496] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_read (err 0)
>
> [  136.370509] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_handle_create (err 0)
>
> [  136.370515] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_prime_pages_to_sg (err 0)
>
> [  136.370550] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_exit (err 0)
>
> [  136.370563] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_release (err 0)
>
> [  136.370565] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_export (err 0)
>
> The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please
> make sure that the kernel source packages are installed and set up
> correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error was caused by missing drm module required by NVIDIA driver.
By default, Ubuntu AMI installs minimal generic Linux kernel(linux-image-virtual), which doesn't include drm module.
To fix it, install the complete generic kernel linux-image-generic.
Installing linux-image-extra-virtual would work as it is merely a transitional package to linux-image-generic. I would suggest install linux-generic to include both headers and image.
To summarize:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

There is similar question asked on [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=558414)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual` did not work for me (ubuntu 14.04, cuda 8.0). However, this solution (`linux-generic`) did.

Comment: An important step after this is to reboot the system via `sudo reboot`. Only, then will the changes get reflected

Answer (score 3):

Actually right after the fresh launch of the GPU instance, `apt-get upgrade` wanted to keep back 4 packages as `linux-virtual`, `linux-image-virtual`. I still installed them so that I got strictly nothing more to upgrade. (The fresh setup doesn't have previous nvidia or any nouveau drivers.)

The thing is that `linux-image-virtual` is a lean build with no `drm.ko`. Just do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

which contains `drm.ko`.

Then go on installing CUDA with either the `.deb` or `.run` file.